# Access DOM inside chrome from native application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, google-chrome, automation

I need to access DOM of web application that is running inside Chrome browser.
Same functionality can be achieved quite easily with IE using 
SHDocVw::ShellWindows and SHDocVw::IWebBrowser2. Now I have to support Google Chrome and it seems that there is no simple way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chrome browser doesn't expose its DOM to external processes. You need to be in process. So in order to access the Chrome browser's DOM you need to be inside a Chrome extension.

Comment: I can not do that. I can not move the whole of my application code into extension. Maybe there is a way to expose the data I need to query from the extension ?

Comment: Nope. You need to be in-proc. You don't need to move all of your app into an extension. You just need an extension that can communicate with your app and act as a go-between.

Comment: The requirement is for native application to query chrome extension. So the problem is now how to expose some callable functionality from the extension